# Prove $|| f||_{H^1}=||f^*||_{L^1}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, normed-spaces, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

The Hardy space $H^1(\mathbf{D})$ is the vector space of holomorphic functions $f$ on the open unit disk that satisfy:
$$
\sup_{0\leq r<1}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\left|f \left (re^{i\theta}\right )\right| \; \mathrm{d}\theta\right)<\infty.$$
The radial limit $$ f^*(e^{i\theta})= \lim_{r \to 1} f(re^{i\theta}) $$
**Question** Prove that $$\sup_{0\leq r<1}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\left|f \left (re^{i\theta}\right )\right| \; \mathrm{d}\theta\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f^*(e^
{i\theta})|d\theta  $$

**Attempt** For $H^1$ functions the radial limit exists a.e. on the circle (Boundary). But how to prove the above equality.?
Also $H^1$ forms a Banach Space.

Comment: Fatou's Lemma shows that $||f^*||_1\le||f||_{H^1}$. The other inequality follows from the fact that $f$ is the Poisson integral of $f^*$.

Comment: David C. Ullrich How does the other inequality follow from $f$ is the Poisson integral of $f*$? .Please write it as an answer. I will happily give it a check mark.

Answer (score 2):

Fatou's Lemma shows that $$||f^*||_1\le||f||_{H^1}:=\sup_{0<r<1}\frac1{2\pi}
\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{it}|\,dt.$$

For the other inequality, note first that $f$ is the Poisson integral of $f^*$. If we define $$f_r(t)=f(re^{it})$$this says that $$f_r=f^**P_r,$$where the $*$ denotes convolution and $P_r$ is the Poisson kernel. All that's relevant here is that $||P_r||_1=1$; now Young's inequality (or someone's well-known inequality) says that$$||f_r||_1\le||f^*||_1||P_r||_1=||f^*||_1.$$Which is qed, since $||f||_{H^1}=\sup_{0<r<1}||f_r||_1$.

Comment: Thanks a ton.I have only 2 doubts - $1.$ How do we get $||P_r||_1=1$?   $2.$In the beginning you wrote that $f$ is the Poisson integral of $f^*$. What does this mean?

Comment: There "must" be a discussion of Poisson integrals wherever this question came from. If not look for "Poisson kernel", "Hardy space", etc on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space

Comment: To be specific, $P_r(t)=\sum r^{|n|}e^{int}$, showing that $\int P_r=1$. Adding two geometric series shows that $P_r(t)=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(t)+r^2},$ so $P_r>0$. Hence $||P_r||_1=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Please give a reference or clarify how you get this from Fatou's lemma?$$||f^*||_1\le||f||_{H^1}:=\sup_{0<r<1}\frac1{2\pi}
\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{it}|\,dt.$$.

Comment: ??? What does Fatou's Lemma say?

Comment: I am so sorry. I only know its statement

Comment: Fatou's lemma is for a sequence of functions $f_n$

Comment: Fatou's lemma is applicable if $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} inf f_n(x)$

Comment: Please answer my last doubt regarding Fatou's Lemma

Comment: There is a sequence $r_n\to1$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}||f_{r_n}||_1=\sup_{0<r<1}||f_r||_1$.

Comment: But in Fatou's lemma we have lim inf.?

Comment: Statement of Fatou's lemma:- Given $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $X\in\Sigma$, let $f_n ; f_n : X \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be **$(\Sigma, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}\geq 0})$-measurable**. Define $f(x) = \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$, $\forall x \in X$. Then $f$ is **$(\Sigma, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}\geq 0})$-measurable** and $\int_{X} f d\mu \leq \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} \int_X f_n d\mu$.

Comment: In the question we have lim sup and here we have lim inf

Comment: In the question we have $\sup$, not $\limsup$. If $(a_n)$ is any sequence of reals it's easy to see that $\liminf a_n\le\sup a_n$.

Comment: In fatou's lemma we have lim inf and in the question we have sup (not lim sup - sorry for that). Then how do we get $ || f^*||_{1}\leq  || f||_{H_1}$?

Comment: I've already answered this. **HINT:** If $A\le B$ and $B\le C$ then $A\le C$.

Comment: Can you please explicitly write A B and C?

Comment: I am sorry I got it. Thanks.

Comment: Last question and I will give you a check mark. Have you read Hardy spaces? Please suggest me a book for it

Comment: Start with the chapter on "Holomorphic Fourier Transforms" in Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis_. Then Garnett _Bounded Analytic Functions" - should keep you busy for a while